# AngularJS/AngularFire Firebase Register Form / Authentication

Tags: angularjs, facebook, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing an AngularJS web application that users AngularFire and Firebase.

I have successfully implemented an Firebase Facebook authentication feature that allows the user to login into the web application using their personal Facebook account.

I also have a registration form that users the Firebase Email/Password authentication feature.

**The Problem**

Ok, so the problem is when the user registers using the registration form, once submitting - the form doesn't redirect to the dash! I know this is because of $routeProvider > Resolve or the .run config but, I can't find the right solution to get both the Facebook and the registration form working with each other.

Any and all advice would help massively!
Thank you.

**HTML**

```
Auth<br/><br/>
<button ng-click="fblogin()">Facebook Login</button>
<br/><br/>
<form novalidate class="loginForm">
  <input type="email" ng-model="loginForm.email" placeholder="Email" required/><br/>
  <input type="password" ng-model="loginForm.password"  placeholder="Password" required/>
</form>
<button ng-click="register()">Register</button>
<button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
```

**App.js**

```
var fblogin = angular.module("fblogin", ["firebase", "ngRoute", "fbfactories", "fbcontrollers"]);

fblogin.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/auth', {
      templateUrl: 'views/auth.html',
      controller: 'authCtrl',
      resolve: {
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
          return Auth.$waitForAuth();
        }]
      }
    })
    .when('/dash', {
      templateUrl: 'views/dash.html',
      controller: 'dashCtrl',
      resolve: {
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
          return Auth.$requireAuth();
        }]
      }
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/auth'
    });
}]);

fblogin.run(["$rootScope", "$location", function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      $location.path("/auth");
    }
  });
}]);
```

**Factory.js**

```
var fbfactories = angular.module('fbfactories', []);

fbfactories.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://courtyard-bridal.firebaseio.com/");
  return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}]);
```

**Controller.js**

```
var fbcontrollers = angular.module('fbcontrollers', []);

fbcontrollers.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$location', function($scope, Auth, $location) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://courtyard-bridal.firebaseio.com/");
  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.user = $scope.auth.$getAuth();
  // Facebook Login
  $scope.fblogin = function() {
    var scope = {
      scope: 'email'
    };
    $scope.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook', scope).then(function(auth) {
      // Redirtect on Success
      $location.path('/dash');
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error');
    });
  };
  // Form Data
  $scope.loginForm = ({
    'email': '',
    'password': ''
  });
  // Register
  $scope.register = function() {
    // Form Data
    var email = $scope.loginForm.email;
    var password = $scope.loginForm.password;
    // Create User
    ref.createUser({
      email: email,
      password: password
    }, function(error, userData) {
      if (error) {
        // Error
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
      } else {
        // Success
        console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
        $location.path('/dash');
      }
    });
  };
}]);
fbcontrollers.controller('dashCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$location', function($scope, Auth, $location) {
  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.user = $scope.auth.$getAuth();
  // Facebook Logout
  $scope.fblogout = function() {
    $scope.auth.$unauth();
    $location.path('/auth');
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fbcontrollers = angular.module('fbcontrollers', []);
fbcontrollers.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$location', function($scope, Auth, $location) {
  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.user = $scope.auth.$getAuth();
  // Facebook Login
  $scope.fblogin = function() {
    var scope = {
      scope: 'email'
    };
    $scope.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook', scope).then(function(auth) {
      // Redirtect on Success
      $location.path('/dash');
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error');
    });
  };
  // Default Form Data
  $scope.form = ({
    'email': '',
    'password': ''
  });
  // Login Form
  $scope.login = function() {
    var email = $scope.form.email;
    var password = $scope.form.password;
    $scope.authData = null;
    $scope.auth.$authWithPassword({
      email: email,
      password: password
    }).then(function(Auth) {
      $scope.authData = Auth;
      $location.path('/dash');
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
  // Register (Create User) Form
  $scope.register = function() {
    var email = $scope.form.email;
    var password = $scope.form.password;
    // Create User
    $scope.auth.$createUser({
      email: email,
      password: password
    }).then(function(Auth) {
      // Login Created User
      $scope.authData = null;
      $scope.auth.$authWithPassword({
        email: email,
        password: password
      }).then(function(Auth) {
        $scope.authData = Auth;
        $location.path('/dash');
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error');
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
}]);
fbcontrollers.controller('dashCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$location', function($scope, Auth, $location) {
  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.user = $scope.auth.$getAuth();
  // Logout
  $scope.logout = function() {
    $scope.auth.$unauth();
    $location.path('/auth');
  };
}]);
```